# Intercepting iphone SMS messages for my own SMS writer/reader

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms

I am looking into a final year project for university and im exploring all possible options. I was thinking about SMS encrypting but with an iphone. I think its possible to send an SMS message via any program I make for the iphone but if i did make said program, would it be able to intercept enrypted messages; instead of those text messages going to the standard SMS program?

I ask this because I know that Apple are very strict about their products and the last time i checked the only way to use another text program was to jailbreak the iphone and I am not keen on doing that.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible without jailbreaking and fiddling with the private APIs, and furthermore, it is against Apple policy. Even with jailbreaking, it is not trivial.